# Why are these html lists merged in this page?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, jsoup

[`http://www.unc.edu/academics/`](http://www.unc.edu/academics/)

I tried to grab all html lists as rendered by `ul` from the page above using Jsoup.

Here's my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.unc.edu/academics/").get();
Elements lists = doc.select("ul");
for (Element list: lists) {
    Elements li = list.select("li a");
    if (li.size() > 0) {
        ArrayList<String> anchors = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element e : li) {
            anchors.add(e.text());
        }
        System.out.println(anchors);
    }
 }
```

Following is the output:

```
[Calendar, Libraries, Maps, Departments, MyUNC]
[About UNC, Academics, Research, Public Service, Health Care, UNC Global, Arts, Athletics]
[Academic Departments, Continuing Education, Distance Education, Provost, Services and Resources]
[Academic Calendar, Courses, Libraries, Registrar, Sakai]
[College of Arts & Sciences, Dentistry, Education, Eshelman School of Pharmacy, Friday Center for Continuing Education, General College, Gillings School of Global Public Health, Graduate School, Kenan-Flagler Business School, Government, Information & Library Science, Journalism & Mass Communication, Law, Medicine, Nursing, Social Work, Summer School]
[Departments A-Z, Departments by Interest Area]
[American Indian Studies, APPLES Service-Learning, Applied Sciences & Engineering, Archaeology, Bioinformatics & Computational Biology Training, Biological & Biomedical Sciences, Burch Fellows, Business (Undergraduate), Carolina Entrepreneurial Initiative, Christianity & Culture, Cinema, Cognitive Science, Comparative Literature, Communication Studies, Creative Writing, Cultural Studies, Developmental Biology Training, Ethnicity, Culture & Health Outcomes, Environment & Ecology, European Studies, First Year Seminars, Folklore, Genetics & Molecular Biology, Global Studies, Honors, Humanities & Human Values, Institute for Environment, Jewish Studies, Johnston Center for Undergraduate Excellence, Languages Across Curriculum, Latin American Studies, Latina/o Studies, Management & Society, Mathematical Decision Sciences, Mathematical Sciences, Medieval & Early Modern Studies, Middle East/Muslim Civilizations, Molecular Biology & Biotechnology, Molecular/Cellular Biophysics, Morehead-Cain Scholarship, Neurobiology, Peace, War & Defense, Philosophy, Politics & Economics, Program on Health Outcomes, Public Administration, Public Health Leadership, Russian/East European Studies, Robertson Scholars, Sexuality Studies, Social & Economic Justice, SPIRE Postdoctoral Program, Stone Center, Study Abroad, SURE, Toxicology, Transatlantic Master’s Program, Undergraduate Curricula, World View, Writing for Screen & Stage]
[Alert Carolina, Contact, Departments, Directory, Employment, FAQs, ITS, Privacy Policy, Accessibility, RSS Feeds]
```

You may notice that three lists as showed in the following image are being merged into one, i.e., the fifth list in the output.

[image]

As you may see in the page source, the three lists are indeed rendered by three `ul` tags. Could it be related to Javascript or CSS embedded in the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code do deliver the list in one piece.

```
<ul class="col3">
<li><a href="http://artsandsci.unc.edu/">College of Arts &amp; Sciences</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.dentistry.unc.edu/">Dentistry</a></li>
<li><a href="http://soe.unc.edu/">Education</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.pharmacy.unc.edu/">Eshelman School of Pharmacy</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.fridaycenter.unc.edu/">Friday Center for Continuing Education</a></li>
<li><a href="http://advising.unc.edu/">General College</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.sph.unc.edu/">Gillings School of Global Public Health</a></li>
<li><a href="http://gradschool.unc.edu/">Graduate School</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.kenan-flagler.unc.edu/">Kenan-Flagler Business School</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.sog.unc.edu/">Government</a></li>
<li><a href="http://sils.unc.edu/">Information &amp; Library Science</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.jomc.unc.edu/">Journalism &amp; Mass Communication</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.law.unc.edu/">Law</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.med.unc.edu/">Medicine</a></li>
<li><a href="http://nursing.unc.edu/">Nursing</a></li>
<li><a href="http://ssw.unc.edu/">Social Work</a></li>
<li><a href="http://summer.unc.edu/">Summer School</a></li>
</ul>
```

But the javascript broke it apart into three separate `<ul>`s.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('div.accordion > ul').makeacolumnlists({
        cols: 3,
        colWidth: '33%',
        equalHeight: false,
        startN: 1
    });
    $('div.accordion > div > ul').accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        header:'> li > h4',
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
    $('ul.col2').makeacolumnlists({
        cols: 2,
        colWidth: 0,
        equalHeight: false,
        startN: 1
    });
    $('ul.col3').makeacolumnlists({
        cols: 3,
        colWidth: 0,
        equalHeight: false,
        startN: 1
    });
});
```

Did the trick.

Comment: Wow fantastic! Now I'm a little confused which one did the trick or both. Since the other answer mentioned CSS while you dumped the JS code.

Comment: If you `document.querySelectorAll('ul')`, you will see three `<ul>`s. So they are separated in DOM tree, and CSS can't do that.

Comment: Now I'm only more confused. You assume they are separated in DOM tree. Under your assumption, Jsoup should return three lists since my Jsoup code parsed the html into DOM tree.

Comment: Jsoup doesn't execute script on the page. so the DOM tree will remain the one you get originally. You can disable javascript in your browser, you will see how Jsoup sees the page.

Comment: That's a brilliant tip. Thanks!

Comment: @TerryLi: Yeah I didn't actually look at the rest of the code, I just guessed CSS

Answer (score 1):

Um.... they're not three lists, it's one list. This is the actual page code. As you can see, it's only 1 `<ul>` tag. It's using CSS to make it appear as 3 columns (`class="col3"`)

I assume if Chrome is giving you incorrect information, it's probably Javascript messing you up.

```html
<ul class="col3">
<li><a href="http://artsandsci.unc.edu/">College of Arts &amp; Sciences</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.dentistry.unc.edu/">Dentistry</a></li>
<li><a href="http://soe.unc.edu/">Education</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.pharmacy.unc.edu/">Eshelman School of Pharmacy</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.fridaycenter.unc.edu/">Friday Center for Continuing Education</a></li>
<li><a href="http://advising.unc.edu/">General College</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.sph.unc.edu/">Gillings School of Global Public Health</a></li>
<li><a href="http://gradschool.unc.edu/">Graduate School</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.kenan-flagler.unc.edu/">Kenan-Flagler Business School</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.sog.unc.edu/">Government</a></li>
<li><a href="http://sils.unc.edu/">Information &amp; Library Science</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.jomc.unc.edu/">Journalism &amp; Mass Communication</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.law.unc.edu/">Law</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.med.unc.edu/">Medicine</a></li>
<li><a href="http://nursing.unc.edu/">Nursing</a></li>
<li><a href="http://ssw.unc.edu/">Social Work</a></li>
<li><a href="http://summer.unc.edu/">Summer School</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that's right, but the chrome's inspector is somehow misleading us.

Comment: Chrome gives me three lists though.

Comment: @xiaoyi: I didn't look at the CSS, it's probably related

Comment: @TerryLi: That dump is from Firefox -> Web Developer -> Page Source. Since your code looks good I assume it's Chrome that's screwing up

Comment: Thank you very much. Without your help, it will take a while for me to suspect it's Chrome.